# Find All Articles by Tag, Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

### The Problem

I have an `Article` entity in *Doctrine*, which has a many-to-many relationship with `Tag`. That is, an `Article` can be "tagged" with multiple tags, and they are bound together by the *articles_tags* table in the database.

Let us assume we wanted to find all `Article`s that are associated with given `Tag`. For the case of an example, let us say we wanted to find all `Article`s associated with the "cars" tag: an article about cars.

### *DQL* as Opposed to *SQL*

Had this been regular SQL (or some flavor of it), I would have written a query in a similar manner to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM articles_tags WHERE tag_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name = 'cars')
```

This would give us all *article_tags* where there is a `Tag` that goes by the name "cars". Of course, should more than one tags be used in the query at one time, duplicate articles should also be thrown out: perhaps by using a `GROUP BY`. Furthermore, you could even get rid of the intermediary step of first selecting the *article_tags* and then going to the `Article`s, by writing a longer query.

From my current understanding of *Doctrine*, which ranges no more than a few days, you cannot directly reference intermediary tables; nor does it seem as though you can write subqueries using the DQL. As such, I am at a loss.

Any pointers as to where I should start writing the query from, or any information regarding how one in general might go about handling these types of database retrievals in an ORM such as *Doctrine* would be highly helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query in DQL is a bit simpler than pure SQL:

```
$q = "
SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Article
LEFT JOIN a.tags t
WHERE t.name = :tag";

$result = $em->createQuery($q)
        ->setParameter('tag', $tag)
        ->getResult()
;
```